Windows batch script find files greater than xxMB and find similar files based on result
i'm struggeling with some batch programming in windows where i didn't get the result i'm looking for.
I do have a folder containing hundreds of files having always a set of 3 files belonging together:
BWMKE_PROD_DAP_WOTERM01_1000_1_280624_100320_5.pdf
BWMKE_PROD_DAP_WOTERM01_1000_1_280624_100320_5_Archiv.xml
BWMKE_PROD_DAP_WOTERM01_1000_1_280624_100320_5_Daten.xml
I would now to move all PDF reaching certain threshold in terms of filesize and their corresponding XML files to a seperate folder.
The PDF piece is already working but how do i get the corresponding XML files identified/moved as well?
Thanks in advance
BR Oliver
that's what i have so far, but forfiles give me an error: Files of type "*.xml not found.
I tried findstr as well, without luck
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "SOURCE_DIR=D:/AFI/S4I/D4P_Prod/Archive/PDF_Orig_Test"
set "DESTINATION_DIR=D:/AFI/S4I/D4P_Prod/Archive/TMP_Dir"
set "FILE_SIZE=5000000"

set "logfile=%date:~-4%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-10,2%.log"

call :main
goto :EOF

:main
echo "%FILE_SIZE%" | findstr ""\[0-9]\[0-9]\*"" > NUL
if errorlevel 1 (
echo An error occured
exit /b 1
)

for /R "%SOURCE_DIR%" %%F in ("*.*") do (
if exist "%%F" if %%~zF GEQ %FILE_SIZE%  (
echo %%F >> "log_big_files/large_files %logfile%"
move "%%F" "%DESTINATION_DIR%"
echo %%~nF
forfiles /M "%%~nF*.xml" /C "cmd /C move \<RESULT> "%DESTINATION_DIR%""
)
)
goto :EOF


Your syntax below used for file size is WRONG:
%%\~zF

Correct syntax:
 %%~zF

The forfiles syntax is also wrong. You are combining path and file mask.
forfiles /M "%%\~nF\*.xml"

Correct way: forfiles /p C:\whateverpath /m *.xml
Also the %%\~nF in your forfiles command seems misplaced.
Also i dont understand why you used <\RESULT>\ in your command.
Without going into what you are trying to do and whether your script's in the correct flow.
This is where you need to begin

See the forfiles documentation. Type forfiles /? in the command line.
Go read about extensions usage: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html

